# Creating js popup on html5 player

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, video.js, popcornjs

I would like to add custom markers on the html5 player (video.js) progress bar that automatically popup a js dialog box when playing the video, sort of like soundcloud.com comments system, it won't be edited from the from the frontend, only hardcoded comments added once, sort of chapters but with popup functionality.

Comment: There is no question, only a wish I see here.

Answer (score 1):

popcornjs is the way to do it.

You can use their editor to facilitate it : https://popcorn.webmaker.org/

Regards